# Quadratic equation $x^2-ax+2a = 0$ with Integers Roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, quadratics

> Find Integer value of $a$ for which both roots of the equation $x^2-ax+2a = 0$ are also integers.

#### My Try

$$x = \frac{a \pm \sqrt{a^2-8a}}{2}$$Now if the roots are integers, then $a^2-8a=k^2$, where $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Now How can I calculate after that? Thanks.

Comment: If $a^2-8a=k^2$ then, completing the square, we get $a^2-8a+16=k^2+16$ and $(a-4)^2=k^2+16$, so $b^2-k^2=16$ (where $b=a-4$).  What is known about Pell-like equations that would apply here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you say, the question comes down to knowing when $a^2 - 8a - k^2 = 0$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.  Solving for $a$, $a = 4 \pm \sqrt{16 + k^2}$.  As you can see, only for $k = 0$ or $k=3$ does this produce an integer solution for $a$ and so $a = 8$, $a = 0$, $a=9$ and $a=-1$ are possible.

The reason why those were the only $k$ values possible is because after a while, the difference between $k^2$ and $(k+1)^2$ is $2k+1$ and so when $k > 8$, $2k + 1$ becomes bigger than $16$.  So we only need to test $k$ up to $8$.

Comment: How about $k = 3$?

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Sorry, I went through a (possibly ongoing) process of "oops" "fixed" "oops" "fixed".  I've addressed that case now.